# How to 2nd highest salary, we have repeated values

Tags: soql

For example, we have salaries like.

18000
17000
18000
16000
18000

Then how can we get the 2nd highest salary?

Thanks,
Rajesh

Comment: Hi @SarojBera, Don't think that handles the repeated values part.

Comment: I've downvoted this because there is no attempt at research or trying it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In Apex you can use a `Set` to eliminate duplicates and then use the `sort` method of `List`:

```
List<Decimal> salaries = new List<Decimal>{
    18000,
    17000,
    18000,
    16000,
    18000
};

Set<Decimal> s = new Set<Decimal>(salariesList);
List<Decimal> l = new List<Decimal>(s);
l.sort();
if (l.size() >= 2) {
    Decimal secondHighest = l.get(l.size() - 2);
    ...
}
```